# Loop through Named Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `named range` for list of report files I have created. They are stored in a folder that matches their file name.

like this - -

List of file is a `Named Range` called `order`

a

b

c

and they are stored in a folder like this:

\folder\a\a_support.xls

\folder\b\b_support.xls

\folder\c\c_support.xls

I am trying to copy each xls file into a master sheet. The list is not in alphabetical order so I need to run through the list and import in the order I currently have. 
I tried making a loop but I couldn't get my named ranges or objects correct.

How would I make a loop using 'i' to run through my list? I will be using the 'i' value to dynamically reference the directory

here's my code as it stands

```
 Sub Move_reports()

    Dim day As String
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wsname As String
    Dim order As Range
    Dim c As Range

    day = Sheets("data").Cells(1, 2).Value
    FromPath = "\local\shared\"& day &"DOCUMENTS\" & i & "\"
    Set c = Worksheets("data").Range(order) _

    For Each c In order
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            wsname = c.Value
            Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
            FromPath & i & "_support.xls" _
            , UpdateLinks:=0
        Sheets(i).Select
        Sheets(i).Copy After:=Workbooks("SEP_FINAL.xlsm").Sheets("BEG")
     ActiveWindow.Close
     SaveChanges = True

    End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by LIST? where do you keep xls file names?

Comment: I have a named list (called 'order') and its a list of each report name. They are all saved as .xls files in their respective folders under the same directory path

Comment: There is no `LIST` in Excel/VBA, you meant it is a `range`

Comment: you don't need to use `Select` when running a VBA code, `Select` is generated when you are recording a macro, but practically there is no need, so you can delete the lines that have `Select` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, if you have a `named range` called `order` to loop through it from top to bottom to keep the order of opening the files you should use something like this in your loop:

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("order").Columns(1) 'change the name of sheet per you need
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
   wsname = rng.Cells(i, 1)
Next i
```

**suggestion:** you don't need to keep the name and order of the files in a `named range` because if the list increases then you have to also modify your `named range`. You can easily pick up the names of whatever number from a sheet column. Let's say you are keeping the names and order in column A of Sheet1 so do this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
   wsname = rng.Cells(i, 1)
Next i
```

Comment: feel free to hit the checkmark and upvote if you are happy with the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the loop! I almost got it working but the value 'i' keeps return is "0" and then "1"

 [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/CInPxYv.png)

Comment: Yes! I had set the path name before initiating the worksheet name so the loop hadnt started and the wsname value had not populated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Heres my finished working code for those looking for the same answer as me

Thank you again Lbo!

all thats left is an 'IfError , next i'

```
Sub Move_reports()

    Dim day As String
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wsname As String
    Dim rng As Range
    day = Sheets("data").Cells(1, 2).Value _

    Set rng = Worksheets("data").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
       For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
        wsname = rng.Cells(i, 1)
        FromPath = "\SUPPORT\" & day & "\DOCUMENTS\" & wsname & "\" _

        Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        FromPath & wsname & "_support.xls" _
         , UpdateLinks:=0
        Sheets(wsname).Select
        Sheets(wsname).Copy After:=Workbooks("SEP_FINAL.xlsm").Sheets("BEG")
        ActiveWindow.Close
        SaveChanges = True
     Next i

End Sub
```